# Show it's not vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$(x1, y1) ⊕ (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2) \ and \  α (x, y) = (αx,0).\ $$

Since addition is the usual way. Tested the axioms of multiplication. I tried to prove that it wasn't $R^2$ vector space using =>
$(α+ β)u = αu + βu$

And using $α(u+v) = αu+ αv$  but I couldn't conclude that it's not vector space. Where did I go wrong?

My calculation ->
$$(α+ β)u = αu + βu$$

$$\displaylines{(α + β)(X_1,Y_1) = α (X_1,Y_1) + β(X_1,Y_1) \\
\\:. (αX_1 + βX1,0) = (αX_1,0) + (βX1,0)} $$

Other axiom:
$$α(u+v) = αu+ αv$$

$$\displaylines{ α((X_1,Y_1) + X_2,Y_2)) = α(X_1,Y_1) + α(X_2,Y_2)  \\
\\:. α(X_1 + X_2,Y_1 + Y_2 ) = (αX_1,0) + (αX_2,0)
\\:. αX_1 + αX_2,0 = αX_1 + αX_2,0} $$

Comment: Use $1\;v = v$.

Comment: Thank you @user3257842. I thought of the most complicated ones